# Geometric Plethysm with Representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ be the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C} = \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{C})$. We follow the convention from Fulton & Harris' Representation Theory book and choose as generators for $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C}$ the matrices $H, X,Y$ given on page 147 and so we obtain the eigenvalue/ weight decomposition $V= V_{-1} \bigoplus V_1= \mathbb{C} \cdot y \oplus \mathbb{C} \cdot x$ such that $H(x)=x$ and $H(y)=-y$ and $X,Y$ are the ladder operators.

Below the Exercise 11.34 (Hermite Reciprocity) on page 160, which asks the reader to use the eigenvalues of $H$ to show that

$$     \text{Sym}^k(\text{Sym}^n V)) \cong \text{Sym}^n(\text{Sym}^k V))   $$

there is a text below which provides a rather interesting geometric picture I would like understand better:

Note that in the examples of the exercise we have seen, it seems completely coincidental: for example, the fact that the representations
$\text{Sym}^3(\text{Sym}^4 V)) $ and $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$  both contain a trivial representation corresponds
to the facts that the tangential developable of the twisted cubic in
$\mathbb{P}^3$ has degree $4$, while the chordal variety of the rational normal quartic in $\mathbb{P}^4$ has degree $3$.

a remark: if we think about $V$ as isomorphic dual space $V^*$ and the generators as monomials $x,y$, then $\text{Sym}^n V$ can be regarded as homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$ of degree $n$.
Moreover, the rational normal curve of degree $n$ can be realized as image under the map $V \to \text{Sym}^n V, v \mapsto v^n$, ie $n$-th power on $v \in V$.

**Question:**
I not understand why the fact that $\text{Sym}^3(\text{Sym}^4 V)) $ and $ \text{Sym}^4(\text{Sym}^3 V))$  both contain a trivial representation $V_0 \cong \mathbb{C}$ corresponds
to the facts that the tangential developable of the twisted cubic in
$\mathbb{P}^3$ has degree $4$, while the chordal variety of the rational normal quartic in $\mathbb{P}^4$ has degree $3$. How to see this geometric interesting connection?

I'm not looking for a formal proof, just a sketchy idea providing this geometric picture would make me happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a copy of the trivial representation in $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ corresponds to an **invariant**, degree $k$, (symmetric) polynomial function on $V^*$ (up to scale). In the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ all representations are self-dual so we can translate this to polynomial functions on $V$.

Then we can see that the rational normal curve must lie in the variety of this polynomial. It certainly lies in an orbit of the $\operatorname{SL}_2$ action since $\operatorname{SL}_2$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and the polynomial is invariant. Thus we only need to test 1 element.

Upgrading this to the tangent developable/chordal variety is probably a case by case thing but I don't know this last bit off the top of my head.

Comment: so this "trick" to relate trivial irreps inside decompositions of reps of form $ \text{Sym}^ n(V)$ to subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}$ coming as vanishing sets of degree n polynomials is far from being a general technique, but arise only from very special ( "accident" ) that here the rep $ V $ is self- dual?

Comment: @JustusC Ah sorry, I just used that to simplify a little bit. If $V$ has an invariant polynomial then so does $V^*$. In other words a trivial rep in $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ implies there is one in $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V^*)$. Thus this idea works for any rep (at least for a semisimple Lie group/algebra but possibly more generally).

Comment: ...I'm not completely sure, why it is true that for any rep $V$, if $V$ has an invariant polynomial, then $V^*$ has one invariant polynom, too (and then of course vice versa)? Can it be constructed explicitly from $f$? Say $f$ is invariant wrt $V$, so $f(x)=f(g \cdot x)$ for all $g \in G$. I'm not sure if $f$ is then invariant with respect to the dual rep $V^*$

Comment: @JustusC Well you want $f(gx_1,\dots,gx_k)=f(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ but yes that is equivalent to $f\in \operatorname{Sym}^kV^*$ being an invariant polynomial but this isnt constructing it from something in $\operatorname{Sym}^kV$ . Loosely speaking the invariant polynomials on $V$,$V^*$ are constructed in the same way. We just don't have an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: so there is at least no explicit way to associate to an invariant $ f \in \text{Sym} V$ a "corresponding" invariant polynomial in $ \text{Sym} V^*$? So just an existence statement... But thinking on  pure abstract level: how to see that if the decomposition of rep $ \text{Sym} V $ has a trivial part, then $ \text{Sym} V^*$ has also a trivial part? I not see it, could you sketch an argument?

Comment: @JustusC Well $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V^*) = \operatorname{Sym}^k(V)^*$ and the dual of a rep is the sum of the duals of its irreducible components, so all you need to know is the trivial rep is self-dual, which it always is. Note I am not saying that it is not possible to construct some dual invariant from the original, just that it is probably easier to do it "by hand". In general you probably just work with $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V^*)$ from the outset anyway rather than converting between the two.

Comment: It is probably worth getting comfortable with how representations can be represented by decorated Dynkin diagrams and how duality can then be thought of as a diagram automorphism. This might be in Fulton and Harris but if not Baston and Eastwood's "The Penrose Transform" gives a great overview of this (and a similar identification for parabolic subalgebras) in its introductory chapters. With that perspective, my previous comment becomes fairly obvious

Comment: alright thank you, I see, so the desired explicitness breaks down in non canonical choice of some isomophism $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V^*) = \operatorname{Sym}^k(V)^*$

Comment: @JustusC No that isomorphism is explicit. The problem would be with an identification of $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ with $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)^*$. In particular that there is no $G$-equivariant one unless the representation is self dual.